# How to split line with python and get the remaining line

Tags: python

I have some lines in my file

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

i'm trying to split line but I'm getting error I want to exclude 0 1 and want to pick the remaining line but how i can do this with python

```
elm1 = line.split()[0]
elm2 = line.split()[1]
elm3 = line.split()[2] +" "+ [3] +" "+ [4] +" "+ [5] +" "+ [6] +" "+ [7]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
>>> line = "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7"
>>> " ".join(line.split()[2:])
'2 3 4 5 6 7'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameter maxsplit

```
>>> s = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8"
>>> s.split(maxsplit=2)
['1', '2', '3 4 5 6 7 8']
>>> elm1,elm2,elm3 = tuple(s.split(maxsplit=2))
```